# Was Neo actually born on 9/11?

Tags: the-matrix

I saw a video on YouTube showing the file on Agent Smith's desk talking about how Neo's birthdate was on September 11th. It's hard to read, and I’m not sure if this was conspiracy, truth, or half-truth.

Was this in the original movie at theatres then edited out by machine AI after the attacks? Are there connections? This might not be too relevant, but the main question is: is the birthdate of "Thomas Anderson" the 11th of September?

Comment: OMG! Laden was a The Matrix fan...

Comment: no, BUT the bad guy in the movie "Enemy of the State", Thomas Brian Reynolds, from the Office of Counter-Terrorism WAS born on 9/11/40.  And that movie came out in 1998.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

No.

The date of **expiration** on his passport is 9/11/01 (11th September 2001).

The date of issuance is 9/12/91 (12th September 1991), precisely 20 years (minus one day) after his date of birth on **9/13/71** (13th September 1971).

[image: Identity page from Thomas A. Anderson's passport]

Interestingly the date of birth on his security file is different, 03/11/62 (11th March 1962). Chalk this one down to a simple production error.

[image: Photo of security clearance for Thomas A. Anderson, showing date of birth as "11 March, 1962"]

Comment: Of course, no *century* is included. But when the Matrix is being explained to him, I think they do describe it as being based on late 20th/early 21st century earth, so it’s fair to say his passport expires on 9/11.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite - It's not clear that in the Matrix, New York even exists. There are no references to it.

Comment: It was an aussie filmed location though. It says Capital City, and in the third as flies to save Morpheus on the two trucks you see the city scope. It's just one mega capital city

Comment: One could explain the date discrepancy by saying the paranoid Mr. Anderson falsified his birth date when applying for a passport.

Comment: @Omegacron - Or hacked whatever database his file is on.

Comment: @Richard - Re New York. Locals call New York "The City" in the real *<wink>* world and that same name is given to Capitol City by characters in the movie. Coincidence? There are no coincidences in the Matrix. ;)

Comment: @Richard - yep, that too. Heck, maybe NEITHER birthdate is the real one.

Comment: @user23715 Reminds me of this old Wikipedia discussion: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:The_City - which, looking at the page history, is still the subject of a slow-motion edit war.

Comment: Where was the scene with the password? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @dolda2000 - If you mean passport, there was a scan of it in Neo's security file during the interrogation scene

Comment: [March 11, 2004: Madrid train bombings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WLB3DVNQ9L4). A [42](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/42_(number)) year difference.