# Does Neo have any back-story?

Tags: the-matrix

I would like to find more information about Neo, ideally something beyond the fact that he's a hacker and was destined to be 'The One'.

During the movie we can see some details about his personal life, for instance that he's a very lonely person, lives alone and that he has some books about philosophy (specifically "Simulacra and Simulation").

What isn't clear is about his family and background interests.
**Is there a complete biography for this character?**

Comment: I fail to see how this is attracting votes for being "too broad". It's not like there's loads to add.

Answer (score 13):

During the [interrogation scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4D7cPH7DHgA) with Agent Smith, we see a file which contains brief details of Thomas Anderson prior to his involvement with Morpheus.

> **Personal Details**
>   **Name:** Thomas A. Anderson
>   **Date of Birth:**  1962-03-11
>   **Place of Birth:** Lower Downtown, Capital City, FU, USA
>   **Mother's maiden name:**   Michelle McGahey
>   **Father's Name:**  John Anderson
>   **Marital status:** Single
>
> **Education Record**
>   **Schools attended:** Central West Junior High School / Owen Paterson High
>
> **High School Record:**
>   Anderson excelled in the sciences, mathematics and computer courses. He also displayed some aptitude for English and History. After some trouble with discipline at the age of 13-14, Anderson settled down to become a fairly well-regarded member of the school community. This was mainly due to an increased involvement in sports, especially football and hockey.

[image]

From the next sheet we get some idea of his work history, flitting from "job to job" due to his inability to cope with authority figures.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the details, all are very interesting I was wondering about his university studies, I mean he could be an Applied Mathematician, Computer scientist or computer engineer, since he is a programmer, if there is not other more complete answer I will proceed to accept this, thanks for the support,

Comment: @neo33 - That's all there is. There's also some biographical stuff from [his passport](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80211/was-neo-actually-born-on-9-11/80212#80212) if you're interested.

Comment: well I understand, Thanks a lot for the details.

Comment: I really wish 'FU' was an actual state.

Comment: FYI: [Michelle McGahey](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0568894/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr19) is the film's Art Director and [Owen Paterson](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0665517/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cr17) is the film's Production Designer.

Answer (score 3):

Thomas Anderson worked as a software programmer for a company in the Captial City in the Matrix. He moonlighted as a 'hacker', possibly exploiting personally-developed zero-day vulnerabilities. Much of this can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo_(The_Matrix)), which provides a good background of the life and family he had while still 'plugged-in'.

As for Simulacra and Simulation, that was a required read for people working on the story and on the set for the Trilogy. There are a lot of references to similar themes throughout the Trilogy and Animatrix.